# Replacing elements in a multidimensional array after a condition

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to replace values in an array once a condition is met in a different array.

Here is what I want to do with code that doesn't work:

```
Dim rng As Variant
    rng = Range("A1:C20").Value
Dim reset As Variant
    reset = Range("D1:F20").Value
Dim newrng As Variant
    newrng = Range("G1:I20").Value

For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
    For j = LBound(rng, 2) To UBound(rng, 2)
        Do Until reset(i, j) = "1"
            rng(i, j) = rng(i, j)
        Loop
        rng(i, j) = newrng(i, j) 'here is where I'm not sure to have a loop or what
    Next
Next
```

Sow what I'm trying to do with this is have the rng stay the same until a condition is met in the row of reset, once this condition is met, from that cell onward I want to replace the remaining values in the row to be from newrng. I have different code that works by computing each cell individually, but this is horribly inefficient when I am doing this on 900,000 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set rng(i,j)=rng(i,j) all the time, use an IF

```
    For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
        For j = LBound(rng, 2) To UBound(rng, 2)
            If reset(i, j) = "1"
                rng(i, j) = newrng(i, j)
        Next
    Next
```

If reset appears only once per row you can set a boolean flag

```
    Dim useNewrng as Boolean
    useNewrng = false

    For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
        For j = LBound(rng, 2) To UBound(rng, 2)
            If reset(i, j) = "1" then useNewrng = true
            If useNewrng then rng(i, j) = newrng(i, j)
        Next
        useNewrng = false 'reset on row change
    Next
```

Comment: + 1 for the boolean check - goes to the heart of the issue.

Comment: The Boolean is perfect for one instance, but if I were to want the second instance to begin replacing with ANOTHER new range, I should use the first method with if? My problem is this is a large data set with 20,000 rows and 130 columns for each of these ranges.

Comment: What do you mean with 2nd instance?

Comment: I would like to change the range again after "1" appears for the second time, etc.

Comment: Change the boolean to a counter and increment each time a 1 is found. Reset to 0 where you set the boolean to false

Answer (score 1):

I've made some change below

- test that each row contains the condition before looping through it
- no need to use `Lbound` on a variant array as it is always 1
- `Value2` slightly quicker then `Value`
- code starts replacement on the column *after* the condition is met

*code*

```
Sub a()
Dim rng As Variant
Dim reset As Variant
Dim newrng As Variant
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim bTest As Boolean
Dim StrFind As String    

rng = Range("A1:C20").Value2
reset = Range("D1:F20").Value2
newrng = Range("G1:I20").Value2

StrFind = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
bTest = False
bFound = IsEmpty(Filter(Application.Index(rng, i), StrFind, True))
    If Not bFound Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(rng, 2)
            If bTest Then rng(i, j) = newrng(i, j)
            If reset(i, j) = StrFind Then bTest = True
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```